# Underscore template: "<string" not displayed, but "< string" is

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js-templating

I found a strange problem with the underscore templates.

`<string` does not display the string with html encoded `<` but returns an empty string instead. But `< string` works correctly. 
Note the space required.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BwHxv/281/

In the fiddle, try adding a space, so you'll see that it works correctly.

Any particular reason? If a user accidentally types this character, it should not turn into an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML string `<string` is the start of a "string" element. It's nonsense, so your browser doesn't show anything.

The HTML string `< string` is just text. It's valid, so your browser shows the text is represents.

The bug is that you pass plain text to a method expecting HTML. The simplest fix is to change

```
.html
```

to

```
.text
```

Comment: Hmm, it works with text. However I use Marionette, which is supposed to render my variables automatically when I feed it a collection of backbone models and it suffers the same problem. Do you have a suggestion? I realise that this is not supposed to happen, but one can never be sure about what a user will input.

Comment: Honestly, I have no familiarity with underscore.js or Marionette -- never heard of them. The other approach would be to have your template system produce HTML, and the other answer appears to tell you how to do that. From what you're saying, it's a better solution for you.

Comment: Thank you. The final problem was related to two libraries I was using: one for loading external templates (tpl), the other for displaying a css styled bootstrap dropdown. I currently fixed the problem, thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Using Underscore's `<%= ... %>` syntax with jQuery's `.html()` will treat the value of `name` as raw markup and, to the browser, `<string` appears to be an incomplete and invalid HTML tag.

To encode a placeholder in the template, so it's rendered as text, you can change the `<%=` to `<%-` (http://jsfiddle.net/0cL4c1yx/):

```
var template = _.template( "<%- name %>", obj );
```

Or, you can instead use jQuery's `.text()` to treat the entire template result as text.